# Excel Formula to Determine Size - 3 variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula.

The variables are:

1 - Type (Copper or Aluminum)

2 - Amps (100, 150 or 200)

3 - Distance (in feet).

Determining the type of wire, the amps the wire will be pushing, and the distance determines the wire type.

Example: if I am using Aluminum type wire, for 100 Amps that is less than 150 ft, I would use type 1 wire.

Second Example: if I am using Aluminum, for 100 Amps that is greater than 150 ft but less than 200 feet, I would use 1/0 wire.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Dimitri

Comment: Do you have a table some where that has the specifications?  If so pleas show it in the OP using edit.  If not how is Excel supposed to know the answer?

Comment: I just need to know how I can structure my if and / or statement. I don't need a real answer, an example in using all 3 variables will be fine

Comment: I would use a lookup table and vlookup, not an if statement,  You will need 5-6 nested if statements to do it, in lieu of one vlookup.

Comment: Actually now that I think of it, you will need more nested ifs than allowed to deal with the length as you will need to have an if for each wire gauge also.  A lookup table is the only real method here.

Comment: please add a screenshot of the excel. We would understand the problem better

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example formula using all three variables as you requested. The scant information in your example is not inclusive enough to construct a formula that will account for all the variables involved.

Column "A" has the wire (aluminum); Column "B" has the amperage and "C" has the length in feet. D1 has the formula: =IF(AND(A1="Aluminum",B1=100,C1<150),"Type 1",IF(AND(A1="Aluminum",B1=100,(AND(C1>150,C1<200))),"1/0","?")).

Two issues: The "1/0" text will produce an error flag in the cell because of an interpretation for a two-year date. Simply click "ignore error" for all these cells. Secondly, the question mark is there because of not knowing what you would want to do with the other variables if the ones within the formula both prove false. This formula is only a partial answer that sees your examples.

Comment: Vlookup worked great. I created different list for each amp and type, so 6 list total (Aluminum & 100 AMP, Aluminum & 150 AMP, Aluminum and 200 AMP, Copper & 100 AMP, Copper & 150 AMP, Copper & 200 AMP). Once this was in place, i was able to use an if statement to make the appropriate vlookup calls.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(D10=100,$L$4=1),VLOOKUP(I10,$A$136:$C$158,3,TRUE),IF(AND(D10=150,$L$4=1),VLOOKUP(I10,$E$136:$G$154,3,TRUE),IF(AND(D10=200,$L$4=1),VLOOKUP(I10,$H$136:$J$149,3,TRUE),IF(AND(D10=100,$L$5=1),VLOOKUP(I10,$K$136:$M$158,3,TRUE),IF(AND(D10=150,$L$5=1),VLOOKUP(I10,$N$136:$P$158,3,TRUE),IF(AND(D10=200,$L$5=1),VLOOKUP(I10,$Q$136:$S$154,3,TRUE),"UNKNOWN"))))))

That ended up being my formula. Worked Great.